# Issue with LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo UI MVC wrappers to create a grid.

The code in the Controller is below:

```
public ActionResult GetFaxHistory([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    using (var faxHistory = new waldenEntities())
    {
        IQueryable<FaxesSendServer> faxHistoryJson
            = (System.Linq.IQueryable<WaldenCompleteFaxWeb.Models.FaxesSendServer>)faxHistory.FaxesSendServers.Where(p => p.UserID.Contains("walden"));
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

This code works and creates the grid with no issues.  When I attempt to select specific fields I get an error:

The code I am using is below:

```
public ActionResult GetFaxHistory([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    using (var faxHistory = new waldenEntities())
    {
        IQueryable<FaxesSendServer> faxHistoryJson
            = (System.Linq.IQueryable<WaldenCompleteFaxWeb.Models.FaxesSendServer>)faxHistory.FaxesSendServers.Where(p => p.UserID.Contains("walden"));

        IQueryable faxHistoryJson
            = (System.Linq.IQueryable<WaldenCompleteFaxWeb.Models.FaxesSendServer>)faxHistory.FaxesSendServers.Select(c => c.Status);

    }
}
```

The error I get is below

> System.InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code
>   Message=Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[System.String]' to type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[WaldenCompleteFaxWeb.Models.FaxesSendServer]'.
>   Source=WaldenCompleteFaxWeb   StackTrace:
>          at WaldenCompleteFaxWeb.Controllers.HomeController.GetFaxHistory(DataSourceRequest
>   request) in C:\waldenltd\Customer
>   Applications\WaldenCompleteFaxWeb\WaldenCompleteFaxWeb\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line
>   48
>          at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c_*DisplayClass42.b*_41()
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c_*DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult
>   _)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c*_DisplayClass37.<>c_*DisplayClass39.b*_33()
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c_*DisplayClass4f.b*_49()
>   InnerException:

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does your code even compile? You are using same variable name for both query results?

Comment: Yes. The code compiles in both examples.  The first code sample(using no select) does not error out.  The select sample code errors out.  Why would selecting all fields work as expected and when I do a select I get the error above?

Comment: Well at least im getting an error saying "A local variable named 'faxHistoryJson' is already declared in this scope."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `c.Status` is returning something other than a `FaxesSendServer`.

If it returns a `string`, you'd need to change it to something like this:

```
IQueryable faxHistoryJson =
    (IQueryable<string>)faxHistory.FaxesSendServers.Select(c => c.Status);
// note the change ^
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to try an answer this question.  The question was poorly constructed and did not explain my real problem.  Your answer put me on the right track to getting the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

faxHistoryJson will be a set of strings not of FaxesSendServer because you are selecting the status.

Comment: Therefore, the cast to IQueryable<FaxesSendServer> is invalid

Answer (score 0):

Your `Select` statement changes the resulting output type.

The first statement just filters the collection and still retrieve `FaxesSendServer`, but your statement gets you the type of the column `Status` (which is int or string maybe).

Answer (score 0):

`LINQ` follow deferred execution. This mean the execution will only trigger when you try to access the result. This is why you are not getting any exception at the first place. In addition, you may need to convert your source to `IQueryable` or using `AsQuerable()` extension method over your projection.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the question was that it was poorly constructed.  The code samples I gave did not adequately describe the problem I was having.

public ActionResult GetFaxHistory([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        using (var faxHistory = new waldenEntities())
        {
            IQueryable faxHistoryJson
                = (System.Linq.IQueryable)faxHistory.FaxesSendServers.Where(p => p.UserID.Contains("walden"));

```
        IQueryable faxHistoryJson
            = (System.Linq.IQueryable<WaldenCompleteFaxWeb.Models.FaxesSendServer>)faxHistory.FaxesSendServers.Select(c => c.Status);

    }
}
```

The code above failed because it was written incorreclty.  The correct code is below:

```
        using (var faxHistory = new waldenEntities())
        {

            var query = from c in faxHistory.FaxesSendServers.Where(p => p.UserID.Contains("walden"))
                        select new
                        {
                            c.SendID,
                            c.Status,
                            c.FaxName,
                            c.CreateTime,
                            c.CompletionTime,
                            c.PageCount,
                            c.RecipientName,
                            c.Notes
                        };


            var faxHistoryJson = from c in query.AsEnumerable()
                    select new
                    {
                        c.SendID,
                        c.Status,
                        c.FaxName,
                        CreateTime = c.CreateTime.ToShortDateString() + " " + c.CreateTime.ToShortTimeString(),
                        c.CompletionTime,
                        c.PageCount,
                        c.RecipientName,
                        c.Notes
                    };

            DataSourceResult result = faxHistoryJson.ToDataSourceResult(request);

            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

The first LINQ statement appears to be the correct way to be the correct way to create the projection.  The second LINQ statement was used to format the date field so it would properly show up in the Kendo UI grid